# Get system tray icons without explorer running

Tags: c#, list, explorer, system-tray

I have been looking for a way to get a list of applications in the system tray without explorer.exe running but all i have found is how to get it when explorer is running. Is there a way to get a list of system tray "applications" when explorer is closed/not running?

Comment: System Tray exists within explorer. So if explorer is not running then there is no system tray.

Comment: Then is there a way I can check if an application would be shown in the system tray?

Comment: I don't think so. Processes that are running decide whether or not they should have an icon in the system tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "system tray" is part of [`explorer.exe`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer). If that's not running, you've pretty much got no desktop.

As far as identifying what goes in the system tray...to get in the system tray, the application must register with the windows shell (aka `explorer.exe`). Until those apps start, you've got no practical way of identifying which apps those might be. And if the shell isn't running, those apps aren't going to be running either.

Comment: Ok then. Thanks for the information. Ill accept this in 5 minutes.